# Shortest path with time constraint

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, path-finding, a-star

Few cities (<=50) are given along with two (N * N) matrices denoting travel time between cities and toll between cities. Now given a time t (<10000), we have to choose a path to reach from city 0 to city N-1 such that toll cost is minimum and we complete travel within given time t.

I am thinking of using A star algorithm to solve the above question. How to I  satisfy both requirement by combining them into a heuristic function ？

Comment: You can run a search (and heuristic) using only the cost. When the target is reached check if the total time is < t. If so, you found the required path. Else, you need to keep searching. To find out how to "continue searching" investigate how to find all possible paths using A* (or BFS. The technique is similar).

Comment: In this case I don't think A* isn't going to be very helpful since you can't really compute a good simple heuristic. I think you will want to go with either some dynamic programming technique (might look like dfs over a bigger graph, in which case you could use A* for the dfs) or (harder) Lagrangian relaxation

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a simple distance score calculation for the heuristic, and use both the tolls and time for cost calculation, as c0der mentioned.

Your A* search should compare all the current paths dynamically though. Remove any loops as usual, and remove the more costly path if two paths reach the same point with a better cost. After each iteration, as the paths list gets reordered by their heuristic scores, better-doing paths will get brought up in that list.